# Radio button layout messed up in Django template

Tags: html, css, django-templates, radio-button

I have Django template where a user fills out her bio, mobile number, age, gender and marital status. Gender and marital status are radio buttons with two options, the former 3 choices are text fields. The template is laid out thusly:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.bio.label_tag }}{{ form.bio }}<p>
  {{ form.mobilenumber.label_tag }}{{ form.mobilenumber }}<p>   
  {{ form.age.label_tag }}{{ form.age }}<p>
  {{ form.gender.label_tag }}{{ form.gender }}<p>
  {{ form.marital_status.label_tag }}{{ form.marital_status }}<p> 
  <input class="button" style="background-color:#F6F6F6" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

This form displays the text field in separate lines, but the radio buttons appear indented. See screenshot:
[image]

How do I make the radio buttons appear inline with the rest of the form? I can't understand why this thing appears like so. My code is bare bones.

**EDIT:**
I don't want to wrap everything in a table because though it fixes the problem, the table isn't responsive for small screen sizes (e.g. feature phones, a key market for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the above code to the following:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.bio.errors }}<p>
  {{ form.bio.label_tag }}{{ form.bio }}<p>
  {{ form.mobilenumber.errors }}<p> 
  {{ form.mobilenumber.label_tag }}{{ form.mobilenumber }}<p>   
  {{ form.age.errors }}<p>  
  {{ form.age.label_tag }}{{ form.age }}<br>
  {{ form.gender.errors }}
  {{ form.gender.label_tag }}<br>{% for radio in form.gender %}<table><tr><label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}"><td><span style="margin-left:2em">{{ radio.choice_label }}</span><span style="margin:auto">{{ radio.tag }}</span></td></label></tr></table>{% endfor %}<br>
  {{ form.marital_status.errors }}
  {{ form.marital_status.label_tag }}<br>{% for radio in form.marital_status %}<table><tr><label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}"><td><span style="margin-left:2em">{{ radio.choice_label }}</span><span class="radio">{{ radio.tag }}</span></td></label></tr></table>{% endfor %}<br>
  <input class="button" style="background-color:#F6F6F6" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect 
What I needed was **granular control** over my radio buttons; the code I've written above gives me precisely that.